# Problems on PID,UFD and factorisation and polynomial rings.

Tags: ring-theory, reference-request, problem-solving

I am an MSc Mathematics first year student,In our first semester course we have Ring theory which includes the following topics:

$1.$ PID

$2.$ UFD

$3.$ Factorisation in $\mathbb Z[i]$

$4.$ Polynomial rings.

Our instructor has completed the theory portion but has not discussed any problems on these topics.I am in search of some nice problems of moderate difficulty on these topics,so that I get a good grasp of these topics.Can someone suggest some assignment sheet,problem book or stackexchange page for this purpose?

Comment: Stackexchange has some hundreds of exercises for these topics. Just an example, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726826/when-is-mathbbz-sqrtd-not-an-ufd-for-d1), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061751/factor-each-of-the-following-elements-in-zi-into-a-product-of-irreducibles). Since you know best what you need to exercise, search yourself a bit.

Comment: The OU's M303 course has a lovely section on Rings and Polynomials (Book C) part of their free Open Learn project. There's a free course based on the material you can sign up for. I'll send you straight to the free PDF but search surrounding pages for more info: https://www.open.edu/openlearn/ocw/pluginfile.php/1116758/mod_resource/content/3/Rings%20and%20polynomials_m303_3.pdf
The section you probably really want is Book E on Rings and Fields but you'll have to buy the book as it's not online. £22.79 from Amazon - https://www.amazon.co.uk/M303-FURTHER-MATHEMATICS-Rings-Fields/dp/1473020409